# Из массива приходит первая буква

Tags: php, smarty

Возникла проблема. Из базы приходит имя картинки в массиве, но когда вызываю в Smatry то получаю только первую букву названия файла, помогите решить проблему.

**Код ниже**

```
{foreach from=$rooms key=id item=val}
        <div class="rooms_content">                 
            <h3 id="h3-options">Что включено:</h3>
            {foreach from=$val["optImagesA"] key=k item=v}
                <img src="./static/images/iconoptions/{$v.optImages}"/> 
            {/foreach}
            <p>{$val.rooms} <a> Забронировать </a></p>

        </div>
    {/foreach}
```

**Debug Smarty**

```
$rooms
Origin: "Smarty object" 
Value
Array (2)
0 => Array (9)
  0 => "4"
  id => "4"
  1 => "80"
  hotelsid => "80"
  2 => "Комната 1"
  rooms => "Комната 1"
  3 => "icon1.png"
  optImages => "icon1.png"
  optImagesA => Array (1)
    0 => "icon1.png"
1 => Array (9)
  0 => "6"
  id => "6"
  1 => "80"
  hotelsid => "80"
  2 => "Room 2"
  rooms => "Room 2"
  3 => "icon2.png,icon6.png"
  optImages => "icon2.png,icon6.png"
  optImagesA => Array (2)
    0 => "icon2.png"
    1 => "icon6.png"
```

**Как приходит значение**

```
<img src="./static/images/iconoptions/i"/>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: В smarty не силён но вы выбираете $val["optImagesA"] в $k и $v где $v будет строкой а вы работаете с ним как с массивом.

Comment: @fens Я даже так пробывал {$v["optImages"]}, но результат тот же(

Comment: Вам нужно просто  $v подставить в uri без указания каких либо индексов

Comment: @fens Спасибо добрый человек дай бог тебе здоровья)).

Comment: Совет на будущее, когда пишешь код, не сокращай имена переменных, вроде $k, $v, $id, $val, например в твоём случае можно так $id = $roomIndex, $val = $roomItem, $k =$imageIndex,$v = $imageName это поможет избегать таких ошибок.